# Existe algum editor de texto com integração com o Github?

Tags: c++, github, lua, notepad++

Estou utilizando Notepad++ para programar na linguagem Lua (programas pequenos, ainda estou estudando), e costumo salvar os códigos no Github quando tenho que parar para continuar depois.

Porém manualmente eu preciso ir até o site do Github e adicionar o arquivo, e se quiser modificar, alterar por lá. No Android Studio há uma integração onde você configura um repositório e depois pode dar commit facilmente. Existe algum editor de texto que faça isso, ou até mesmo uma IDE que suporte Lua?

Na verdade, isso também seria útil para outras linguagens, como C++ e Java.

Comment: O Atom e o Visual Studio Code tem. Mas mesmo no Notepad++, você não precisa adicionar cada arquivo manualmente pelo Github, podia usar a linha de comando...

Comment: eu baixei o Atom agora, você sabe qual package tenho que instalar?

Comment: Esse vídeo explica como usar o Atom com o Git: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Id1_VfbEKo